# ¿Como hago en react un checkbox que sleccione a todos los otros checkbox?

Tags: reactjs

Estoy haciendo un lista de checkboxes y para eso me base en esta página http://react.tips/checkboxes-in-react/, me resultó muy util. Pero ahora necesito agregar otro checkbox que seleccione a todos los anteriores. Como lo haría basandome en lo que hay en la pag?. Sino, me podrian decir otra forma de hacer esa lista de checkboxes y ese checkbox adicional que checkea o desckeque a todos los anteriores en react (igual prefiria el de la pag).

Answer (score 1):

Simple. Primero hay que tener siempre en cuenta que en React se trabaja con **elementos controlados**, esto es, elementos que serán controlados por el estado de React para cambiar y/o mutar. Dicho esto, es realmente simple.

Ten en tu estado valores booleanos para cada checkbox (true|false). Ahora, para cada checkbox debes asignarle el mismo evento, digamos `onCheck` y pasarle como parámetro, *el nombre del checkbox*. Dentro de este método actualizas el estado cambiando el valor `true` o `false` para ese checkbox y al mismo tiempo, poniendo en el estado el resto de checkboxes como `false`.

**Ejemplo**

```js
class CheckBoxExample extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      checkboxes: {
        c1: false,
        c2: false,
        c3: false,
        selected: null,
      },
    };
  }
 
  onCheck(name, val) {
    const checkboxes = Object.assign({},this.state.checkboxes, {});
    for (let key in checkboxes) {
      checkboxes[key] = false;
    }
    checkboxes[name] = true;
    checkboxes.selected = val;
    this.setState({ checkboxes });
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <label>Seleccionado: {this.state.checkboxes.selected}</label><br />
        C1 <input 
             type="checkbox" 
             value="c1"
             checked={this.state.checkboxes.c1} 
             onChange={(e) => this.onCheck('c1', e.target.value) }
           />
        C2 <input 
             type="checkbox" 
             value="c2"
             checked={this.state.checkboxes.c2} 
             onChange={(e) => this.onCheck('c2', e.target.value) }
           />
        C3 <input 
             type="checkbox" 
             value="c3"
             checked={this.state.checkboxes.c3} 
             onChange={(e) => this.onCheck('c3', e.target.value) }
           />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const node = document.getElementById('root');
ReactDOM.render(<CheckBoxExample />, node);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: que pasa si son miles de elementos? peor aun si tengo que enviar los valores de estos hasta el servidor?

Comment: @Shassain Pues creas un componente Checkbox que encapsule el input y su lógica, luego creas un array con objetos que tengan la información de los miles de checkbox que vas a usar. Finalmente, mapeas ese array y por cada objeto devuelves un componente Checkbox. Si quieres optimizar puedes memoizar los componentes.